# App is crashing if using Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, attributes

I addded a new attribute (of type boolean) into my core data model and my data.swift class. I try to run my app after I added the attribute. All works fine. Now I try to work with the new attribute. I wrote some code, which work is working with the attribute. Now I tried a 2nd time to run the app. It's crashing. I get the line of code, where the error occurs. But the line of code which I get has nothing to do with the attribute, which I've added new. The line, where the error occurs is working with another attribute in the core data model but not with the attribute which I've added new. Does someone knows a solution for this?

My data.swift class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(data)
class data: NSManagedObject {

 @NSManaged var aufgabe: String
 @NSManaged var datum: NSDate
 @NSManaged var hatDatum: Bool    //new attribute

}
```

The crashing line:

```
cell.textLabel!.text = "\(daten[indexPath.row].aufgabe)"
```

The error message: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) There's nothing written in the console.

My data model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzlxi30a5mrez52/Bildschirmfoto%202015-02-01%20um%2014.39.42.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you try deleting the app from the device or simulator, and re-running it ? This will clear out if this is a issue with the data migration or not.

Comment: I deleted the app a few times but it's not the reason of the crash.

Comment: Just for the sake of safety (I don't think this is really the problem here but that might be one in the future), when you have an optional, avoid using the `!` unwrapping without checking if the optionnal is `nil`. To be more safe, instead of `cell.textLabel!.text = [...]`, use the `?` operator to make it like  `cell.textLabel?.text = [...]`. The '?' will check if the optionnal exist (if there is a textLabel in the cell), and if not, it will not try to execute the rest of the line and crash.

Answer (score 4):

Reset the simulator or delete the app. It's a conflict in you data model files.

Comment: I deleted the app a few times but it's not the reason of the crash.

Comment: Does it crash on a specific  line?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the line in my question (`cell.textLabel!.text = "\(daten[indexPath.row].aufgabe)"`).